# Random image function Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, loops, conditional-statements

I am attempting to write my first custom JavaScript function and am running into some hurdles.

I am attempting to have three thumbnails on my webpage and have my code grab three images from a selection of many and display them on load.
The problems I am running into revolve around duplication of images or being able to handle when an image is chosen twice(which are similar problems).
I have tried many different conditionals and just cant seem to break through.

here is my code:

```js
let imgThumbnails = document.querySelectorAll('.img-fluid');
let chosenNums = [];

let imgNumber = () => { //object random
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (Object.keys(pictures).length));
}

const pictures = {
    0 : { "src" : "Images - Copy/crack_plant.jpg", "alt" : "Seedling growing through bricks"},
    1 : { "src" : "Images - Copy/desert_botanical.jpg", "alt" : "Phoenix's Desert Botanical Garden"},
    2 : { "src" : "Images - Copy/LookUp.jpg", "alt" : "Looking up through forest"},
    3 : { "src" : "Images - Copy/LookUpLeaves.jpg", "alt" : "Looking up at leaves"},
    4 : { "src" : "Images - Copy/Road_Through_Trees.jpg", "alt" : "A path covered by trees"},
    5 : { "src" : "Images - Copy/Sand.jpg", "alt" : "Tiny balls of sand formed by crabs"},
    6 : { "src" : "Images - Copy/Snow.jpg", "alt" : "Powder day at Breckenridge"},
}; // these images are hosted locally for me at the moment

//attempt 1

const imgPopulate = () => {
    imgThumbnails.forEach( a => {
        let pictureNum = imgNumber();
        while (!chosenNums.includes(pictureNum) && chosenNums.length <= 3) {
            a.src = pictures[pictureNum].src;
            chosenNums.push(pictureNum);
        }
    });
}

imgPopulate();


//attempt 2

while (chosenNums.length <= 3) {
    let pictureNum = imgNumber();
    if(chosenNums.includes() !== pictureNum) {
        for(let i = 0; i <=3; i++) {
            imgThumbnails[i].src = pictures[pictureNum].src
            chosenNums.push(pictureNum);
        }
    } 
}

//attempt 3
do {
    for(let i = 0; i <=3; i++) {
        let pictureNum = imgNumber();
            if(chosenNums.includes() !== pictureNum) {
                imgThumbnails[i].src = pictures[pictureNum].src
                chosenNums.push(pictureNum);
            } else {
                continue;
            }
    }
} while (chosenNums.length <= 3);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="views/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Showin Photos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <img id = "photo1" class="img-fluid" src="" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <img id = "photo2" class="img-fluid" src="" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <img id = "photo3" class="img-fluid" src="" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>



<script src="views/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Attempt:
1: this one works sometimes unless it hit a number from the pictures object that has already been used. then it just displays a blank thumbnail. I believe the problem with this is because its using forEach. so it is only running it once per item even if it gets used before and my while loops doesn't effect it.

2/3: i get the same problem from both of these attempts. These attempts will occasionally use the same picture for different thumbnails. I also get a :"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of undefined" and this is in relation to "pictures[pictureNum].src", BUT all the thumbnails still get filled with images?!?!

If any help can be given either with help fixing this code or if you have another way I should try to write this so I can try that.
As I said this is my first attempt at a custom function and I feel like I am getting tunnel vision and am not able to really look at it from different angles.

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following concept:

1. Convert the pictures into an array using [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and shuffle the array.

```
// see shuffle options in the snippet
const data = shuffle(Object.values(pictures));
```

2. As the data is now shuffled, just grab the first 3 items from the array using [array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
const selected = data.slice(0, 3);
```

You can do it in one line if you use Flavios Copes sort to shuffle:

```
const selected = Object.values(pictures).sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5).slice(0, 3);
```

Snippet below:

```js
const pictures = {
  0: {
    "src": "Images - Copy/crack_plant.jpg",
    "alt": "Seedling growing through bricks"
  },
  1: {
    "src": "Images - Copy/desert_botanical.jpg",
    "alt": "Phoenix's Desert Botanical Garden"
  },
  2: {
    "src": "Images - Copy/LookUp.jpg",
    "alt": "Looking up through forest"
  },
  3: {
    "src": "Images - Copy/LookUpLeaves.jpg",
    "alt": "Looking up at leaves"
  },
  4: {
    "src": "Images - Copy/Road_Through_Trees.jpg",
    "alt": "A path covered by trees"
  },
  5: {
    "src": "Images - Copy/Sand.jpg",
    "alt": "Tiny balls of sand formed by crabs"
  },
  6: {
    "src": "Images - Copy/Snow.jpg",
    "alt": "Powder day at Breckenridge"
  },
};

// shuffle array using Durstenfeld shuffle algorithm 
function shuffle(array) {
  for (let i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [array[i], array[j]] = [array[j], array[i]];
  }

  return array;
}

// convert to an array and shuffle
const data = shuffle(Object.values(pictures));

// grab the first 3
const selected = data.slice(0, 3);

console.info(selected);

// one liner using Flavios Copes sort 
console.info(Object.values(pictures).sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5).slice(0, 3));
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok, well first, you don't need an object that has numeric keys. That's essentially an Array. And an array will give you the features you need here more simply than an object will.

You just need your `while` loop to check to see if the random image from the array it has just picked is already one that was picked, which you can do by storing the resulting randoms separately.

```js
let pics = document.querySelectorAll(".img-fluid");
let chosenNums = [];

let getRandom = () => { 
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * pictures.length);
}

// An object with sequential numbers for keys is essentially an array
// so just use an Array.
const pictures = [
    { "src" : "Images - Copy/crack_plant.jpg", "alt" : "Seedling growing through bricks"},
    { "src" : "Images - Copy/desert_botanical.jpg", "alt" : "Phoenix's Desert Botanical Garden"},
    { "src" : "Images - Copy/LookUp.jpg", "alt" : "Looking up through forest"},
    { "src" : "Images - Copy/LookUpLeaves.jpg", "alt" : "Looking up at leaves"},
    { "src" : "Images - Copy/Road_Through_Trees.jpg", "alt" : "A path covered by trees"},
    { "src" : "Images - Copy/Sand.jpg", "alt" : "Tiny balls of sand formed by crabs"},
    { "src" : "Images - Copy/Snow.jpg", "alt" : "Powder day at Breckenridge"}
]; 

// Keep looping until we have 3 randoms
while(chosenNums.length < 3){
  let random = getRandom();  // Get a random
  // Check to see if the random is NOT already in the output array
  if(!chosenNums.includes(random)){
    chosenNums.push(random); // It's not so add it
  }
}

// Now that the output array has 3 randoms in it, loop over them
chosenNums.forEach(function(num, index){
  // Set up the img element corresponding to the loop index
  // with the data from the picture corresponding to the index
  // in the array of randoms
  pics[index].src = pictures[num].src;
  pics[index].alt = pictures[num].alt;  
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col">
        <img id = "photo1" class="img-fluid">
     </div>
     <div class="col">
        <img id = "photo2" class="img-fluid">
     </div>
     <div class="col">
        <img id = "photo3" class="img-fluid">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```